# Figure out if every tile is loaded

Tags: openlayers, tiles, loading

Is there a way to figure out if every tile of an **ol.source.TileWMS** is loaded?

My attempt so far is the following:

```
var tileColl = new ol.Collection()
tileColl.on('change:length, function(e){
     if(e.target.getLength === 0){
        console.log('ready!');
    }
});
tileWms.on('tileloadstart, function(e){
    tileColl.push(e.tile);
}
tileWms.on('tileloadend, function(e){
 tileColl.remove(e.tile);
}
```

Unfortunately, this fails because sometimes all tiles in the list are loaded before all tileloadstart-Events are fired -eventually the collection becomes empty. (Probably because the number of request send by the browser is limited)

I removed all interactions, so the user cannot move the view. I know I can solve the problem by using (for example) **ol.source.ImageWMS** but I prefer using **ol.source.TileWMS** because it has some visible progress when the tiles are loading.

Some ideas I had but could not make them work:
Calculate the number of tiles that are to load,
Figuring out the last tile which is to load.

Is there way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found a solution to get the number of tiles that are to load. I hope this is reliable.

`var tg= (_tileWMS.getTileGrid()) ? ol.tilegrid.getForProjection(_view.getProjection()) : _tileWMS.getTileGrid(); //if you do not use default tileGrid
var z = tg.getZForResolution(_view.getResolution());
var tileRange=tg.getTileRangeForExtentAndZ(_view.calculateExtent(_map.getSize()),z);
var xTiles = tileRange['maxX']-tileRange['minX'] +1; 
var yTiles = tileRange['maxY']-tileRange['minY'] +1;
_tilesToLoad = xTiles*yTiles;`

Note that some of the used functions are not part of the documentation, so they might change them in a future release without any further hint.

Comment: It looks like the API did indeed change and break this method in v4 - this doesn't work in v4.6.5.